# Values are not symmetric in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table in tableau where it counts the number that Item 1 and Item 2 occurred together. However, the result only gets value based on Item 1.

Ex.
Transaction 1: A->C = 1

Transaction 2: A->C = 1

Transaction 3: A->C = 1

Transaction 4: C->A = 1

Transaction 5: C->A = 1

Transaction 6: C->A = 1

Result for C->A = 3, and A->C = 3. I want to get the total for Item 1 and Item 2 regardless of the order. So for A->B, B->A result should be total of 6. Hope you could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your data needs a pivot. Tableau prefers data in the following form.

transaction, item, count, order_in_transaction

- trx_1, A, 1, 1
- trx_1, C, 1, 2
- trx_2, A, 1, 1
- trx_2, C, 1, 2
- trx_3, A, 1, 1
- trx_3, C, 1, 2
- trx_4, C, 1, 1
- trx_4, A, 1, 2
- trx_5, C, 1, 1
- trx_5, A, 1, 2
- trx_6, C, 1, 1
- trx_6, A, 1, 2

When you data looks like this, then the order of the items doesn't matter and you can use Tableau's grouping plus count distinct.

item,  COUNTD(transaction) will yield

- item C, 6
- item A, 6

order_in_transaction,  item,  SUM(Number of Records) will yield

- 1, A, 3
- 1, C, 3
- 2, A, 3
- 2, C, 3